# Intel Fortran External Library Linking Issue

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to create a Fortran project that uses two different libraries. One is a static lib and one is a dll. The static lib uses the `default` calling convention. The dll uses the `iface:cref` calling convention. If I use either on their own everything is fine by changing the Calling Convention project setting; however, I can't seem to get the compiler options to get the project to build using both. Is there a way to get this to work?

Using Intel Fortran 2019 and Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further discussion in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/844361 but the basic issue is that, on Windows, Intel Fortran's default is to upcase routine names, but `/iface:cref` downcases names. My advice was to not use options such as `/iface` and use `BIND(C,NAME=)` or directives to change naming behavior.

Comment: While in the linked thread I end up using another solution due to my unique and current situation, this is the best general case solution. Is there a way to apply this binding as an interface or wrapper in the using project rather than the original used library in the case of not having access to the library code?

Comment: As I hinted in my answer, you can declare an explicit interface using a "language binding attribute" BIND(C), including a NAME= specifer that gives the spelling and case of the name you want to use. The compiler will then add whatever "decoration" would be used by the "companion C processor", for example, a leading underscore.